# Android Elements not displaying

Tags: android, layout

I'm working through the MyFirstApp tutorial on http://developer.android.com using the latest SDKs.

I've created a 4.1 app and set up my emulator with LCD density of 213, a VM application heap of 48 and a device RAM size of 512.  The resolution is 720x1280.

When I first got this I had "Android" flash up on the emulator.

I noticed that my layout main.xml had not been created by default so I added it myself in res/layouts

I added the following main.xml and strings.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <EditText android:id="@+id/edit_message"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:hint="@string/edit_message" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/button_send" />
</LinearLayout>



<resources>
    <string name="app_name">My First App</string>
    <string name="edit_message">Enter a message</string>
    <string name="button_send">Send</string>
</resources>
```

Now when I run my emulator I just get a black screen.  My guess is that either I've not added main.xml correctly or there's something wrong in my xml file.

Comment: Did you do the setContentView(R.layout.main) method in your onCreate() method of your activity?

Comment: iam trying your code perfect working..

Comment: @SiddharthLele Your comment on the activities pointed me in the right direction, I'd  not correctly set it up in the start wizard. If you post an answer I will accept it.

Comment: I think it's problem of the emulator configuration that wants to use the GPU of your computer and doesn't work properly. Try to create an Android virtual machine with api 2.3 and look if it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Map your XML file (main.xml) to your Activity by using the following statemetn in your Activity's `onCreate()` method:

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);
```